# Fail to start EurekaServer: Consider defining a bean of type 'com.netflix.appinfo.ApplicationInfoManager' in your configuration. spring cloud netflix

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I create project eureka and time to start is lauching this error:

> *************************** APPLICATION FAILED TO START
>
> ---
>
> Description:
>
> Field applicationInfoManager in
> org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EurekaServerAutoConfiguration
> required a bean of type 'com.netflix.appinfo.ApplicationInfoManager'
> that could not be found.
>
> The injection point has the following annotations:
>
> - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
>   2
>
> Action:
>
> Consider defining a bean of type
> 'com.netflix.appinfo.ApplicationInfoManager' in your configuration.

My project contain only main class annoted with `@EneableEurekaApplication` and `@SpringBootApplication`

That's my code

Main class

```
package com.jeterson.dio.servicediscovery;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EnableEurekaServer;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaServer
public class ServiceDiscoveryApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ServiceDiscoveryApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

application.properties

```
spring.application.name=eureka-server
server.port=8761

eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.jetersonn.dio</groupId>
    <artifactId>service-discovery</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Service Discovery</name>
    <description>Eureka Server</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR9</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>


        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Obs: I already tested with most recently version of spring and spring-cloud and have same error.

Comment: I don't see anything specific that should yield the error you are getting. Please try to run the following demo https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/eureka, and if successful, maybe go from there.

Comment: Hello, this demo get same error for me

Answer (score 0):

Replace your configuration with

> spring.cloud.service-registry.auto-registration.enabled=false
> eureka.client.serviceUrl.registerWithEureka=false

Or you can remove the below configuration if you have in your properties file.

```
eureka.client.enabled=false
```